# ¿Como guardar varias fotos o archivo en de un type file input con javascripts o Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input-file

Junto con saludarle, necesitaba saber como puedo guardar en un array de javascripts varias fotos.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
          <div class="hiddenfile">
                    <input id="file_foto" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>
                </div>
          <button id="btnSacaFoto" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100%">Sacar Foto</button>
```

en el JS:

```
var contador_foto=0;
var fotos_celular_array = [];
$("#file_foto").change(function () {
     file_foto = document.getElementById("file_foto").files.length;
     fotos_celular_array.push(document.getElementById("file_foto"));
     contador_foto++;
    $("#file_foto").val('');    
});
```

Pero justamente la primera foto me guarda en el array fotos_celular_array, pero despues no guarda nada, al hacer inspección del codigo me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En metodo para guardar la foto es el siguiente:

```
var fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append("cotizacion", cotizacion);


    for (var i = 0; i < contador_foto; i++) {
        var file = fotos_celular_array[i].files[i];
        debugger;
        fileData.append("Document", file);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Fotos/GuardarFoto',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fileData,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Pero al intentar guardar me sale el inspecionar undefined:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber en que estoy fallando, cual es mi error, y como corregirlo.
Las fotos debo subirla de una en una.

Desde ya, gracias por su atención.

Comment: intenta eliminando cambiando `fotos_celular_array[i].file[i] ` por  `fotos_celular_array[i].file`

Comment: @Bryro, pero no me resultó, sale con lengh=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia a lectura de tus archivos puedes ejecuta y ve el ejemplo en el fragmento de código.

Referencias: [Como leer archivos locales](https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/file/dndfiles//)

```js
var puedeLeerArchivos;
// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
  puedeLeerArchivos =true;
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
  puedeLeerArchivos =false;
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var output = [];
    var fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append("cotizacion", 1200);
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
     var file = f;
        debugger;
        fileData.append("Document", f);
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
    }
    /*
    // Aquí haces la petición
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Fotos/GuardarFoto',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fileData,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    */
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```